# ∞ symbol in external pdf disappears when used as figure

Tags: graphics, symbols, pdf

I'm trying to embed an external pdf as a figure in some latex. However, there is an ∞ symbol in the external pdf that always disappears. How do I resolve this?

[Included pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ure0ylhy3p2c2pn/external.pdf)

Latex code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{external.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[Generated PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ht3cw4m6aefpc66/test_infinity_bug.pdf?dl=0)

Image of included pdf:
[image: External pdf]

After being used as a figure:
[image: External pdf with infinity missing]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{external.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Didn't expect it to be something so simple >.<

Comment: Could you perhaps explain in your answer what you changed? Just posting code is not a full answer.